# How to get a Django form to save?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, cs50

I am trying to make an e-commerce site (CS50 Project 2) that allows its users to save bids on different listings through a Django form. The bid should only save if it is equal to or greater than the listing price or greater than all other bids. The code was previously working, but now the form will not save. How do I get it save if it meets the requirements?

views.py

```
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings.objects, pk=id)
    listing_price = listing.bid
    sellar = listing.user
    bid_form = BidsForm()

    #code for the bid form
    bid_obj = Bids.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    other_bids = bid_obj.all()
    max_bid =0
    for bid in other_bids:
        if listing.bid > max_bid:
            max_bid = listing.bid

    if request.method == "POST":
        bid_form = BidsForm(request.POST)
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            new_bid = bid_form.cleaned_data.get("bid")
            if (new_bid >= listing_price) and (new_bid > max_bid):
                bid = bid_form.save(commit=False)
                bid.listing = listing
                bid.user = request.user
                bid.save()
            else:
                return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                    "auction_listing": listing,
                    "form": comment_form,
                    "comments": comment_obj,
                    "bidForm": bid_form,
                    "bids": bid_obj,
                    "message": "Your bid needs to be equal or greater than the listing price and greater than any other bids."
                })
        else:
            return redirect('listing', id=id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "bidForm": bid_form,
        "bids": bid_obj
    })
```

(There is another form in this views, but it is working fine, and I do not think it is causing a problem with this form.)

forms.py

```
class BidsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bids
        fields = ['bid']
        widgets = {'bid': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'bid': 'Add a bid for this listing here.', 'class' : 'form-control'})}
```

models.py

```
class Bids(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000000000, decimal_places=2)
```

bid form in html

```
<!--bid form-->
        {% if message %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST" name = "newBid">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ bidForm }}
            {{ bidForm.errors }}
            <input type = "submit" value = "Place Bid">
        </form>
        {{ bidForm.errors }}
```

form's generated html

```
        <form action = "/listing/1/" method = "POST" name = "newBid">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="6qfLncNswjG3KsadfAjAOORRnfQp9Q78waK61Jawwh0eGg9tjAhpq4NAFA2Y6lq4">
            <tr><th><label for="id_bid">Bid:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="bid" step="0.01" required id="id_bid"></td></tr>
            
            <input type = "submit" value = "Place Bid">
        </form>
```

entire views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings.objects, pk=id)
    #code for comment and bid forms
    listing_price = listing.bid
    sellar = listing.user
    comment_obj = Comments.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    #types of forms
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    bid_form = BidsForm()

    #close listing code
    if sellar == request.user:
        closeListingButton = True
    else: 
        closeListingButton = False
    closeListing = ''
    try:
        has_closed = get_list_or_404(CloseListing, Q(
            user=request.user) & Q(listings=listing))
    except:
        has_closed = False
    if has_closed:
        closeListing = False
    else: 
        closeListing = True
    
   #watchlist code
    add_or_remove_watchlist = ''
    try:
        has_watchlists = get_object_or_404(WatchList, Q(
            user=request.user) & Q(listing=listing))
        print('--------------------------')
        print(has_watchlists)
        print('--------------------------')
    except:
        has_watchlists = False

    if has_watchlists:
        add_or_remove_watchlist = True
    else:
        print('it will from remove')
        add_or_remove_watchlist = False

    #code for the bid form
    bid_obj = Bids.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    other_bids = bid_obj.all()
    max_bid =0
    for bid in other_bids:
        if listing.bid > max_bid:
            max_bid = listing.bid

     #checks if request method is post for all the forms
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        #forms
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        print("POST", request.POST)
        bid_form = BidsForm(request.POST)
        print("FORM", bid_form)

        #watchlist code
        if request.POST.get('add'):
            WatchList.objects.create(user=request.user, listing=listing)
            add_or_remove_watchlist = False
        elif request.POST.get('remove'):
            add_or_remove_watchlist = True
            has_watchlists.delete()

        #close listing code
        if request.POST.get('close'):
            CloseListing.objects.create(user=request.user, listings=listing)
            closeListing = True
            closeListingButton = False
        else:
            closeListing = False

        #checks if comment form is valid
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.listing = listing
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
        else:
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

        #checks if bid form is valid
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            print('!!!!!form is valid')
            print("bid form is valid")
            new_bid = bid_form.cleaned_data.get("bid")
            if (new_bid >= listing_price) and (new_bid > max_bid):
                bid = bid_form.save(commit=False)
                bid.listing = listing
                bid.user = request.user
                bid.save()
                print("bid form is saving")
            else: 
                print(bid_form.errors)
                print("bid form is not saving")
                return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                    "auction_listing": listing,
                    "form": comment_form,
                    "comments": comment_obj,
                    "bidForm": bid_form,
                    "bids": bid_obj,
                    "message": "Your bid needs to be equal or greater than the listing price and greater than any other bids."
                })
        else:
            print(bid_form.errors, bid_form.non_field_errors)
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

        #what happens if listing is closed
        if closeListing == True:
            closeListingButton = False
            has_watchlists.delete()
            winner = max_bid.user
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                        "auction_listing": listing,
                        "comments": comment_obj,
                        "bids": bid_obj,
                        "closeListingButton": closeListingButton,
                        "closeListing": closeListing,
                        "closedMessage": "This listing is closed.",
                        "winner": winner
            })
        else: 
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": comment_form,
        "comments": comment_obj,
        "bidForm": bid_form,
        "bids": bid_obj,
        "watchlist": add_or_remove_watchlist,
        "closeListingButton": closeListingButton
    })
```

Everything in the code works except the bidForm and the closeListing code, which I am currently working on, but that shouldn't interfere with fixing the bidForm.

Comment: In your template you can output {{bidForm.errors}} to see if there is anything in particular causing problems with your form's validity.

From the problem description there is something required to be unique in your bid that fails once the user has made one bid. IF neither of these give you enough to solve the issue, please post the form and the model for a closer look.

Comment: @SamSparx, I was not able to see any output using the {{ bidForm.errors }}. I also deleted all the bids within the Bids Model to see if it would work again, but now the bids are not saving at all. I added my form and model for you to take a look.

Comment: At this point, you might want to put some print() statements are various points in your code and check the output in your terminal. Eg, print("bid form: ", bid_form) after that variable has been created, or print("valid) after the form passes that test.  If you're not familiar with how to check those, you can add the same to the message that gets generated, eg, message+= "bid form: " + bid_form". This will tell you at what point things fail, and, hopefully, a little about what's missing. You could also try {{bidform.non_field_errors}} in your template and see if there's anything there.

Comment: @SamSparx, I added print statements in my code and received this message: ```<ul class="errorlist"><li>bid<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
[12/Jun/2022 12:23:30] "POST /listing/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0```. Do you know what could be going on?

Comment: looks like you have a problem in the HTML of your form so the field is either not being submitted, or is called soemthing else. I've updated my answer, but if that doesn't solve it, please provide the form section of your html template.

Comment: @SamSparx, I added the form's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of max_digits=1000000000000

```
max_digits=12
```

You are counting the number of digits, not providing the largest number it should except.  I think you have exceeded the bounds of what the database can handle. YOu will need to remigrate the model.

Further debugging
You will need to change to the following:

```
   for bid in other_bids:
        if bid.bid > max_bid:
            max_bid = bid.bid
```

Comment: I changed the max_digits in my Django model, but nothing is happening when I try to submit the form.

Comment: Can you also please provide the html that django generates for the form?  Right click on your page and select view source, then find the form and paste that it.  I can't see anything obvious in your code that's wrong, and django should be handling the name of the field correctly.  The only other thing odd I can see is you've set a 'bid' attribute in your widget, which should probably be 'title', but I can't see that breaking anything.  Maybe fix it to be sure.

Comment: @SanSparx, I added the generated HTML. The line that you added to your answer did not work; it just created another input box that did nothing. Also, my views is larger than what I shared here. It has another form, but I don't think that is causing any problems because they were both previously working fine. Please let me know if you would like to see any other code.

Comment: The extra line was in case you were building the form by hand, but you're using django to do it, so it should be fine. Try printing request.POST and seeing what is inside the post request.

Comment: this is what's inside the post request: ```<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['F1QaOOeHbruE0OaMD1I6qHJrH1A7upXR5LlvslBLbpOPWC92H1GV2XFaZmMGrUgN'], 'bid': ['10']}>```. It's the csrf token along with the amount that was submitted.

Comment: Amended answer with debugging step to try.

Comment: I changed the code to your debugging code and received this in the console ```<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['I2lr1474S11kRtWx0zWUVIGb0qOSGzbvhTLP8sNhcjbBkRx1IhJSJ6yhVRWOwG58'], 'bid': ['15']}>
POST <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['I2lr1474S11kRtWx0zWUVIGb0qOSGzbvhTLP8sNhcjbBkRx1IhJSJ6yhVRWOwG58'], 'bid': ['15']}>
FORM <tr><th><label for="id_bid">Bid:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="bid" value="15" step="0.01" required id="id_bid"></td></tr>```. It says form and post, so I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I reconstructed this offsite, and it works fine for me (except for the bug I have added to the answer). Whatever is causing the validity fail must be elsewhere. Is it possible to post the entire view?

Comment: I added the entire view. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: try adding bidform code above watchlist code. If it works, lower it block by block to see which section makes it fail.

Comment: it works if it is above the watchlist code, but the watchlist code stopped working. When I brought the bidForm code back down, no errors occurred, but the form still wouldn't do anything. Do you know how to fix this without messing up the other code?

Comment: I placed the watchlist code below the bodForm and returned it line by line. Somehow now both things are working. Do you know what caused this error or if the order matters? Thank you for trying to help me solve this problem.

Comment: You'd need to compare before and after line by line to truly say. Might have been a typo, or a wonky indent. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: I was testing my code today and this part ```(new_bid >= listing_price)``` is not working. The form is requiring that the new_bid be greater than the listing_price. Would you know how to make it so that the greater than or equal to symbol would work?

Comment: Please see my comment on 'further debugging' in my answer. This will happen because you are using listing.bid in your loop to set max_bid, rather than bid.bid.  (remember the loop is for bid in other_bids - listing.bid is something else.

Comment: I was able to fix that but am having further problems. Would you mind looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72636075/why-will-only-the-top-form-in-order-in-django-view-work-while-the-one-under-it)?